# Hubo un fallo al cargar el <script> con fuente “http://localhost/curso/assets/js/auth/login.js”

Tags: javascript

soy nuevo en esta comunidad, estoy siguiendo un curso de php, he creado un archivo js y al parecer mi link del archivo esta mal , ya lo revise el link y esta bien solo que me aparece este mensaje : Hubo un fallo al cargar el  con fuente “http://localhost/curso/assets/js/auth/login.js”.
Como navegador estoy usando firefox.

Agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Buenas Tardes, para poder darte una mejor ayuda te sugiero que pongas el código que estas usando.

Comment: Hola, de manera respetuosa te sugiero lo siguiente: nosotros no tenemos acceso a la forma en la que tienes definida la ruta de los archivos ni sus componentes allegados, por lo tanto se nos es imposible decirte que debes cambiar con la poca informacion ofrecida, otro punto curioso es que el navegador en este caso no tiene nada que ver con el error, posiblemente te hayas olvidado de que tienes que tener un servidor local corriendo para poder usar la ruta `localhost`, por eso no carga tu pagina.

Comment: Otra cosa mas: tu carpeta `curso` debe estar en este caso dentro de una carpeta hosteada por el servidor local, no puede estar en cualquier carpeta, por ejemplo en `xampp` la ruta es `C://xampp/htdocs/`, si usas linux es `opt/lampp/htdocs`, en wampp me parece que es en la carpeta `www`, esto depende de que servidor local estes usando ya que recuerda que `PHP` es un lenguaje del lado del servidor, por ende solo funcionara mediante un servidor que lo procese, (no puedes abrirlo sin mas).

Comment: Agradezco mucho sus observaciones, estoy usando xampp y estoy corriendo mi proyecto en mi servidor local.

Comment: He resolvido mi error, mi problema fue que yo tenia agregada mi carpeta assets dentro de la carpeta application, y esto es incorrecto ya que assets no pertenece a application, Muchas gracias por sus comentarios y ayuda.